# sprintf variable number of pointers from an array

Tags: c, printf

```
void *buffer[10];
int size = backtrace(buffer, 10);
char cmd[1024];
sprintf(cmd, "addr2line -f -p -e a.out %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p",
    buffer[0],
    buffer[1],
    buffer[2],
    buffer[3],
    buffer[4],
    buffer[5],
    buffer[6],
    buffer[7],
    buffer[8],
    buffer[9],
);
```

I have this code, works most of the time, but sometimes `size` is less than `10`, how to easily print `size` pointers from an array `buffer`?

Comment: Use a loop. (sprintf() returns the number of written characters or -1)

Comment: Why are you using `void *`?

Comment: @EdHeal, `man backtrace` suggested `void**` as the first argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about a loop where you'd format the pointer in a temporary buffer (with leading space), then concatenate it with the command prefix:

```
int size = backtrace(buffer, 10);
char cmd[1024] = "addr2line -f -p -e a.out";
char buf[20]; // should be enough to hold pointer value
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   sprintf(buf," %p",buffer[i]);
   // you could even check the size here in case cmd+buf overflows cmd size
   strcat(cmd,buf);
}
```

or for performance purists, since `strcat` computes the length every time, we could use the return value of `sprintf` to print in the buffer directly. Slightly more complex but avoids the quadratic string length computation effect:

```
char cmd[1024] = "addr2line -f -p -e a.out";
int i;
char *current = cmd + strlen(cmd);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   int nb_written = sprintf(current," %p",buffer[i]);
   if (current+nb_written > cmd+sizeof(cmd)) break;  // avoids buffer overflow
   current += nb_written;
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, it's not optimal in terms of performance / quadratic. That could be improved with pointers, yes

Comment: shoot, just edited to the same solution as yours (well almost)

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop. `sprintf()` returns the number of written characters or -1:

---

```
void *buffer[10];
char cmd[1024];
int size,idx;
size_t pos, len;

size = backtrace(buffer, 10);
pos = sprintf(cmd, "addr2line -f -p -e a.out");
for(idx=0 ; idx< size;idx++){
        len = sprintf(cmd+pos, " %p", buffer[idx] );
        if (len<0 || len+pos >= sizeof cmd) break;
        pos += len;
        }
```

---

Or, if you want to respect the size of `cmd[]`, use `snprintf()`:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int backtrace(void**, int);

void joop(void)
{

void *buffer[10];
char cmd[1024];
int size,idx;
size_t pos, len;

size = backtrace(buffer, 10);
pos= snprintf(cmd,sizeof cmd, "addr2line -f -p -e a.out");
for(idx=0 ; idx < size; idx++){
        len = snprintf(cmd+pos, sizeof cmd - pos, " %p", buffer[idx] );
        if (len < 0 || len+pos >= sizeof cmd) break;
        pos += len;
        }
}
```

Comment: You could use `len = snprintf(cmd + pos, sizeof(cmd) -pos, " %p", buffer[idx]);` and a different error check to prevent buffer overflow, could you not?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, I was just adding the `snprintf()` thingy.

Answer (score 1):

If the maximum size of the array is explicitly capped at `10`, you can get away with a very minor modification: simply trim your format string at the appropriate point

```
void *buffer[10];
int size = backtrace(buffer, 10);

char format[] = "addr2line -f -p -e a.out %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p %p";
format[24 + size * 3] = '\0';

char cmd[1024];
sprintf(cmd, format,
    buffer[0],
    buffer[1],
    buffer[2],
    buffer[3],
    buffer[4],
    buffer[5],
    buffer[6],
    buffer[7],
    buffer[8],
    buffer[9]
);
```

There's nothing wrong in supplying excessive variadic arguments to a variadic function.

Of course, the exact spot for inserting that `'\0'` should be calculated in a more readabale and maintainable way, not by using "magic constants" as in my example above.